# There is no scaling_max_freq sys file

Tags: kernel, drivers, yocto, cpu-frequency

I checked my Linux sys file, I don’t have:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

My kernel config doesn’t have CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE, and it still didn’t use acpi-cpufreq driver.

The sys file here only created when intel_pstate enabled?

I am using yocto environment, not CentOS or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**
The reason the path won't show on your system is that the cpufreq driver isn't loaded. This driver is the one creating the /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuY/cpufreq in sysfs and populating it with values. When trying to compile the kernel without CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE, it is forced to enabled by the pcc_freq and acpi_freq driver compilation prerequisites, so I guess you must set it in order to compile the driver.

**More details**
Looking at the kernel code under drivers/cpufreq/, we can see that the scaling_max_freq entry in sysfs is defined and maintained by cpufreq.c. There are two drivers implementing the cpufreq functionality - **pcc_cpufreq** and **acpi_cpufreq**. In order for the path to be initialized one of the cpufreq drivers must be loaded.

Relevant fields in kernel config:

```
#
# CPU frequency scaling drivers
#
CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE=y
CONFIG_X86_PCC_CPUFREQ=m
CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ=m
```

Check your system for **pcc_cpufreq** driver. If it is available you should use the cpufreq path without loading **acpi_cpufreq**, but since you said CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE isn't set in your kernel config file, you might be missing all of the cpufreq drivers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think Intel-pstate will also use cpufreq core ( then create the sys files ), not just pcc_cpufreq and acpi_cpufreq, isn't it?